# Generating a HTML Excel file in ASP.NET and packaging in zip file

Tags: asp.net, .net, excel

I am working on a page that generates a HTML Excel file and writes it to the response.  I want to modify that page to generate a number of HTML Excel files and package them as a zip.

I have got it working, but when I try to open the Excel file from the zip file it displays the pure HTML instead of formatting it correctly, like it does when I serve the HTML Excel file directly to the response.

I am using the [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) library for the zip component:

What can I do to get Excel to display the file correctly?

Here is my code:

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + progName + "_" + teacher.GetSchoolId() + ".zip");
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";

byte[] strBytes = String.Format(@"
    <table>
    <tr><td colspan='8'><h1>{0} - {1}</h1></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Activity: </b>{2}</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Teacher: </b>{4}</td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>School: </b>{3}</td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>School ID: </b></td><td>{7}</td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>School Address: </b>{8}</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    </table>
    <table>
    {5}
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    </table>
    <table>
    {6}
    </table>
    <br />
    <p>The averages above are calculated as a percentage of the students who have <b>submitted</b> answers from your school and nationally.</p>
    ",
        DateTime.Now.Year.ToString(),
        ProgramId.SelectedItem.Text,
        ProgramActivityId.SelectedItem.Text,
        teacher.GetSchoolName(),
        teacher.GetFullName(),
        awardKey,
        xls,
        teacher.GetSchoolId(),
        teacher.GetSchoolAddress()
        ).GetBytes();

using (var zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.AddEntry(progName + "_" + teacher.GetSchoolId() + ".xls", strBytes);
    zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
}

Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple; I needed to encode the string properly, then it worked.

```
using (var zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.AddEntry(progName + "_" + teacher.GetSchoolId() + ".xls", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sReport));
    zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
}
```